Issue with writing to a text file in C using printf()
I'm trying to write to a file in C, so quite simple stuff. But I am encountering an issue with the below code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int num;

    fptr = fopen("C:\\test.txt","w");

    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter your number");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Your number is: %d",&num);
    fprintf(fptr,"%d",num);

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}

It never prints the value of num, and the text file always just ends up with an incorrect value.
I've tried over and over again to fix the problem, changing the values I put into it, trying to fiddle around the with the MGM compiler I am using to see if it's a compiler issue, to no avail. I've even tried copying other C code that writes to text files, only to get the same issue.
It always just writes 0.
When I run it, it looks like this -
Enter your number3
3
Your number is: 3

But the value being entered is always 0.

You're not checking the return value from scanf() so you don't know if the value was properly read or not.

Please take the full and complete console input and output, and copy-paste it (as text) into your question.

By the way: printf("Your number is: %d",&num)... Are you sure you should use the pointer-to operator & here?

That's the issue - there is no output. I just put in a number, and the program ends.

Try something even simpler: A main function with a single printf("Hello world\n");. Does that work? How do you build? How do you run?

The output you added clearly shows a '3' as input and output. What does it mean when you write "It always just writes 0." and "But the value being entered is always 0."

Perhaps you're mistaking the output for the programs exit-code (what the main function returns)?

Suggestion: can you rewrite your program as a filter? Instead of writing to both stdout and a file make it simply write to stdout. If the user really wants a file she can do so78671731.exe > C:\test.txt

The printf function expects the value of num itself, not the address of num. Passing the address of num causes undefined behavior, which leads to incorrect output.
You should just drop the & operator.
It should be:
printf("Your number is: %d", num);

instead of:
printf("Your number is: %d", &num);

BTW: you did it right in fprintf(fptr,"%d",num).

printf("Your number is: %d", &num);

The ampersand operator is used to print the address of num variable.
If you want to print the value of num then you should write
printf("Your number is: %d", num);

